# How do I find a tutorial about how to do this with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, frontend

http://bestbefore.ro/ Is the website that caught my eye and I really want to build something like that because it looks fun. But I have got no clue whatsoever on how that way of doing thing is called. I would greatly appreciate either guidance on where to find such a tutorial or the name of the technique so that my google-goo gets more accurate. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you will find a tutorial that will explain how to build each and every interaction on that site. Start smaller. Ask specific questions about specific elements.

Comment: Yeah. That'll be nice. But what am I looking at? How do I google it? The thing is that actually the js file on the site is not obfuscated or anything so I read through it. Is it just JQuery positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different techniques used there:

The movements of 'windows' can be done pretty easily with [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

The scrolling can be done in many ways, but one solid way is [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html).

The portfolio 'carousel' (the dot navigation menu and sliding images) can be done in many ways as well, one of the most common being [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/), but an even sleeker implementation can be found in [ZURB's Orbit slider](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider).

It'll take some graphic design skill to get it all to look great, and some effort to make it work across different platforms/browsers, but it's very doable. Have fun with it!

Comment: Great! Thanks! Actually this is what I was looking for. Yeah I see really no practicality on something like this but yes a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know anything about jQuery then the W3 Site is a great place to start http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Relating to your site query, I would suggest that you use the Firefox extension Firebug to explore the code which is already there and find out what it is doing.

You can use the script panel in Firebug to stop the code at certain points and then step through it line by line. You can also use the inspect tool to identify html elements of interest, and find out where they are located in the jQuery code.

If you notice anything that you don't recognise then your options are:

- head over to the jQuery site and search through the documents which are very comprehensive,
- could try adding keywords you see into Google
- describe what you are trying to do into Google and mention you are tyring to do it with jQuery
- or come back here and post another question